# Regex for identifying all kinds of spaces to be used as a delimiter for exploding a string into an array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, character-encoding, explode

I'm not proficient with regular expressions so when I needed to identify if a paragraph (post excerpt in Wordpress) started with the word "by" and if it did to apply a CSS class to the word "by" and the next two words I did so by exploding the string into an array delimited by space, manipulating the array and then imploding it.

Something weird is happening though. The " " delimiter doesn't work on all spaces (and there are no double spaces being used). Are there multiple versions of the space character out there?

Shouldn't my whole site have the same encoding type and therefore there only be one space character?

If I edit one of the problem posts and delete the first couple of spaces and replace them with new spaces, the code works fine.

My code is below (I know I declared a lot of variables):
The part under the elseif{ is specifically what I was describing, but I pasted the whole conditional block for reference.

```
$byLine = strtolower(string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(),1));
$storySnippet = string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(),16);
$storyExplode = explode(' ', $storySnippet);

if (($byLine=="by") && strtolower($storyExplode[3])=="and") {
    $storySlice = array_slice($storyExplode, 6);
    $storyLast = implode(' ', $storySlice); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="byline">
    <?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(),6); ?></a>
    <?php echo "  ".$storyLast."&hellip;";

} elseif ($byLine=="by") {
    $storySlice = array_slice($storyExplode, 3);
    $storyLast = implode(' ', $storySlice); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color:#888;font-style:italic;font-size:90%;">
    <?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(),3); ?></a>
    <?php echo"  ".$storyLast."&hellip;";

}  else { 
    echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(),16)."&hellip;"; 
}
```

EDIT:

Currently using **preg_split('|\s+|', $storySnippet)** instead of exploding the array with ' ', but I'm still experiencing the same problem.

[Live on adovatedaily.com, 3rd entry under the "opinion" column](http://advocatedaily.com) halfway down the page.

EDITx2:

Converted one of the problem strings to hex. "By Jen" converts to **4279c2a04a656e**. There's no **20** in there and there appears to be an extra character.. what gives?

Comment: Have you tried `preg_split('/\s+/', $str);` instead of `explode(' ', $str);` ?

Comment: Still doesn't work with /\s+/ or |\s+|, it's like the author of the test in the string isn't using regular spaces.. could these be spaces in a different language, under a different encoding type?

Comment: You can check with a hex editor, spaces are `20` in hex format.

Comment: Shows up as a 20 when converted to hex (I copied the string out of the Wordpress editor). Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Okay, I did it with dechex() this time and "By Jen" converts to "4279c2a04a656e" no spaces... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I discovered that the space in question that was causing the problem was a non breaking space (c2a0 in hex).

I successfully replaced my string's white space with regular spaces using the line below, solving the problem.

```
$spacedExcerpt = preg_replace('/\xC2\xA0/', ' ', get_the_excerpt());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_split('|\s+|', $storySnippet);
```

It matches any whitespace character. The + takes care also of double (tripple...) spaces.

Comment: Still doesn't work with /\s+/ or |\s+|, it's like the author of the test in the string (wordpress post) isn't using regular spaces.. could these be spaces in a different language, under a different encoding type?

Comment: It might help to add u modifier, to capture some extra utf whitespaces: '|\s+|u'. If that does not help, post here hex dump of the string.